# UniqueID from three fields and retrieve data

Tags: ms-access, jet-sql

I have one table, 10 fields(f1-f10).
Combining f1-f2-f3 gives me a new field.
I would like to retrieve all data from table, for distinct values of this new field(f1-f2-f3).
Running sub-queries, but getting all records.
Please suggest.

vik

Answer (score 0):

*Group By* those three fields, and choose *Min, Max, Avg, First*, or *Last* for the remaining fields.